# Black & white TV episode about a man who discovers he is a robot (not: "In His Image" or "The Electric Ant")

Tags: story-identification, tv

Black & white '60s TV episode; A young man, dark hair, wearing khakis & a plaid shirt(?) is in town when he hurts himself, cutting his arm/wrist open, only he doesn't bleed.  Instead he sees wires inside his arm, and ends up finding his way to the basement laboratory where he was made, eventually discovering he is not human, but a robot.

I thought the actor was George Maharis (not). I thought it was a *Twilight Zone* episode or *The Outer Limits* (not).  It was definitely a short (30 minute) episode of some syndicated show very much like TZ.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like there were a _lot_ of anthology series like *The Twilight Zone*; maybe you can find it in an episode guide for one of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthology_series#Science_fiction_and_horror

Answer (score 5):

Well, if I had the ability to bend over and let all of you kick me in the backside, I would, but  the answer is in fact the *The Twilight Zone* S04E01, **"[In His Image](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734578/)"** (1963).

> A young man grapples with an urge to kill and confusion about his origins.

I take no pleasure in admitting I made a mistake.  I don't know how I did it, except to say that I remembered so little of the episode that in previewing "In His Image" and watching the first fifteen minutes, it stirred absolutely no recollection whatsoever AND the sample images at IMDB actually show the wires in the arm wound on #17 of 18 images.  I hope I didn't send you all on too much of a great big goose-chase!  I promise never to darken this website ever again.

[image: Image of an android wrist with exposed wiring, from the "The Twilight Zone" S04E01, "In His Image" (1963).]

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting arrows.

Comment: Don't let one bad experience drive you off.  My first interaction with this board wasn't very smooth either.  But the folks here generally know of what they speak so if they give you an answer check it out fully.

Answer (score 1):

It might The Outer Limits: The Demon with a glass hand?, it's not exactly as I remember it but it's pretty close I guess.  https://www.solie.org/alibrary/OuterLimits_205DemonWithaGlassHand.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Is there any extra info you could [edit] in to motivate why you believe this is what the OP is looking for? Any matching details, a synopsis?

Comment: The OP [answered their own question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/242961/122024), and the answer they gave was the _The Twilight Zone_ episode "In His Image."

Answer (score 0):

This could be 'The Brain of John Emerson', a 1955 episode of 'Science Fiction Theatre'. The synopsis on IMDB is very short, but it is about a man, after a brain operation, who begins to remember things he didn't experience. These memories lead him to the home of the deceased surgeon who operated on him; finding the surgeon's lab, he discovers he can operate the equipment. It does not give away the ending.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good match. It's in colour, whereas the OP said the episode they were thinking of was in black & white. Also, [the episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SR4ENzYWUI) is up on YouTube, and  I couldn't find a scene where the protagonist's arm or wrist is cut open, exposing wires.

Comment: Nope, not it.  My episode was in black and white.